# ¿remover alertas datatables 1.10v?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Existe una configuración para quitar o ocultar las alertas de Datatables 1.10v,

```
$('#tabla_repuestos').DataTable( {
   "paging":   false
} );
```

Ejemplo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica tu codigo, algo esta mal al mostrar los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error sale por que has especificado dos veces este que `#tabla_repuestos` es un dataTables algo como esto:

```
$('#tabla_repuestos').dataTable( {
    paging: false
} );

$('#tabla_repuestos').dataTable( {
    searching: false
} );
```

Revisa la pagina que te indica esa alerta te dan mas razones del porque esa alerta y las posibles soluciones que puedes hacer

http://datatables.net/th/3

Una de ellas es:

1. Colocar las opciones dentro de un mismo inicializador del plugin

```
$('#tabla_repuestos').dataTable( {
    paging: false,
    searching: false
} );
```

2. Destruir la tabla anterior y volver a inicializar el plugin con las nuevas opciones

```
table = $('#tabla_repuestos').DataTable( {
    paging: false
} );

table.destroy();

table = $('#tabla_repuestos').DataTable( {
    searching: false
} );
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> Esas alertas solo se pueden quitar modificando el plugin.
>
> De haber modificado el pluguin quitando las alertas no podrás saber cual es el motivo del que falla en algún futuro y quedaras peor